# When I run my code for not doubling numbers on a bingo board, Visual Studio builds successfully but the code does not show up on the console

Tags: c#, console

I created a bingo board with random numbers, and I am trying to ensure that none of the numbers on the bingo board are repeated. In order to do this, I created a method CheckDouble(). Although the code looks good to me and does not build error, it is not displaying on the console. Does my code make sense, and what can I do to improve it so that it builds efficiently?

```
static int[,] card = new int[5, 5];
static Random rand = new Random();
static void PopulateCard()
{
    int num = -1;
    int counter = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < card.GetLength(0); row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < card.GetLength(1); col++)
        {
            do
            {
                if (row == 2 && col == 2)
                    num = 0;
                else if (col == 0)
                    num = rand.Next(1, 16);
                else if (col == 1)
                    num = rand.Next(16, 31);
                else if (col == 2)
                    num = rand.Next(31, 46);
                else if (col == 3)
                    num = rand.Next(46, 61);
                else
                    num = rand.Next(61, 76);
            }
            while (CheckDouble(counter, num));
            counter++;
            card[row, col] = num;
        }
    }
}
static bool CheckDouble(int num, int counter)
{
    int[] nums = new int[25];
    nums[counter] = num;
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    {
        if (nums[i] == num)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You might consider making this a [mcve]. It would probably be helpful to you to step through the code in a debugger and see if what it does is what you expect.

Comment: Maybe think about the logic in `CheckDouble` a bit. What value will the items in `nums` that are not `nums[counter]` have? Do you really want another array there? Shouldn't you check against the values in `card`? Consider that it might be easier to fill a list with 1-15. For each column shuffle the list, take the first N values from it, and multiply each by the 1-based column index to shift the values into the right range. You'll never have a duplicate that way.

Comment: Hi, can you write me the code needed to create a bingo board in the way you described? Thank you.

Comment: Have you [asked a rubber duck](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)? Just explain to the duck what is going on as you step through the program in the debugger. That `while` loop looks quite small. What changes in it?

Comment: This code does not contain any output calls.

Comment: You'll want to use a *single* `Random` object rather than create a new one in a loop.  **Definitely** research shuffle a set of numbers to make your cards.  It is much more efficient than your checking for 'doubles' approach.  There are tons of questions and loads of code here dealing with all your problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so your original code had a some of issues, but this should give you what you want.

```
static void PopulateCard()
{
    int num = -1;
    int counter = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < card.GetLength(0); row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < card.GetLength(1); col++)
        {
            do
            {
                
                if (col == 0)
                    num = rand.Next(1, 16);
                else if (col == 1)
                    num = rand.Next(16, 31);
                else if (col == 2)
                    num = rand.Next(31, 46);
                else if (col == 3)
                    num = rand.Next(46, 61);
                else
                    num = rand.Next(61, 76);
            }
            while (CheckDouble(num, counter));
            counter++;
            card[row, col] = num;
            Console.WriteLine(counter);
        }
    }
    card[2, 2] = 0;
}
static bool CheckDouble(int num, int counter)
{
    int[] nums = new int[25];
    nums[counter] = num;
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    {
        if (nums[i] == num)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Basically: when you call CheckDouble(num, counter), you mixed up num and counter AND your code enters a endless loop once you hit row 2 and col 2 since 0 will always be seen as a double.

I however see that you still get doubles from time too time so this would be my way of rewriting your code

```
static void PopulateCard()
{
    int num = -1;
    int counter = 0;
    List<int> nums = new();
    for (int row = 0; row < card.GetLength(0); row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < card.GetLength(1); col++)
        {
            do
            {
                if (col == 0)
                    num = rand.Next(1, 16);
                else if (col == 1)
                    num = rand.Next(16, 31);
                else if (col == 2)
                    num = rand.Next(31, 46);
                else if (col == 3)
                    num = rand.Next(46, 61);
                else
                    num = rand.Next(61, 76);
            }
            while (nums.Contains(num));
            counter++;
            card[row, col] = num;
            nums.Add(num);
        }
    }
    card[2, 2] = 0;
    
}
```

And here is an alternative:

```
public static void PopList()
{
    PopCol(1,0);
    PopCol(16, 1);
    PopCol(31, 2);
    PopCol(46,3);
    PopCol(61, 4);
    
    card[2, 2] = 0;
}

public static void PopCol(int min, int col)
{
    List<int> possibleValues = Enumerable.Range(min, 15).ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        int randIndex = rand.Next(possibleValues.Count);
        int val = possibleValues[randIndex];
        card[i, col] = val;
        possibleValues.RemoveAt(randIndex);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I do apologize for the frequent edits